# How I can simplify this code? convert file json to array json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this json file, and I'm turning into a json array, everything works fine, but the real json file contains more data.
How to simplify this code could either change the javascript or json file.

```
{
"Subject1":{
    "Biology":{
        "Category":{
            "Cell":{
                "question1":{
                    "que1":"what's....?"
                },
                "question2":{
                    "que2":"what's....?"
                },
                "question3":{
                    "que3": "what's....?"
                }
            },
            "Bactery":{
                "question1":{
                    "que1":"what's....?"
                },
                "question2":{
                    "que2": "what's....?"
                },
                "question3":{
                    "que3": "what's....?"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

this is my code witch convert the file json into array json of javascript:

```
var exa = [];
function show() {
    $.getJSON('questions.json', function (json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var item = json[key];
                exa.push({
//I want to simplify this part, because the real json file have more questions
                    que1: item.Biology.Category.Cell.question1.que1,
                    que2: item.Biology.Category.Cell.question2.que2,
                    que3: item.Biology.Category.Cell.question3.que3,

                    que11: item.Biology.Category.Bactery.question1.que1,
                    que12: item.Biology.Category.Bactery.question2.que2,
                    que13: item.Biology.Category.Bactery.question3.que3

                });
            }
        }
        //return Books;
        console.log(exa)
    })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by simplify?

Comment: make the code more short, because my real json file, have more data i want simplify this part exa.push({.......})

Comment: Why don't you parse your JSON data and create an array instead of push in an array...

Comment: @chikatetsu How would you propose to make it shorter?

Comment: If you are free to change the JSON file, why don't you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of que1, que2, etc., just have the questions in an array

```
"Cell": [
    "what's this?",
    "what's that?"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json-path](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/) and write `JsonPath.read(json, "$..question");` to get all questions. You need to change all `que[*]` in your file to `question` too.